# .NET Query Builder component

Tags: c#, .net, sql, components, uicomponents

Can anyone reccomend a free .NET libary which allows you to expose a SQL Query builder to your users in a windows form app?  I'd like my users to be able to run relatively straight forward SELECT statements, including some JOINS and other multi-table operations without getting into the real nitty-gritty of SQL.

Thanks,
sweeney

Comment: Exposing a query builder to your users seems like a bad idea. Are you sure you want to let your users run their own queries? That sounds like it could open up some pretty serious security concerns.

Comment: @Dan As long as you limit the tables a user can connect to and the types of actions run against it (e.g. CONNECT, SELECT only), should be ok, no?

Comment: Yea well i dont want them running INSERTS or UPDATES or DELETES, or really anything aside from SELECT.  Its geared toward a smart but not necessarily technical audience.  One of the apps I have in mind geared toward the research community - they'll understand what they are doing and wont have malicious intent.  With my other application, if they do somehow manage to wreck the db with a SELECT statement, the data can easily be duplicated.  So I dont consider this a problem at all.

Comment: @Nick - right theres no real harm that can come from running select statements right?

Comment: Additionally most DB engines will allow you to specify which tables a user can even look at...

Comment: @sweeney: select * from [User] can be pretty dangerous...

Answer (score 4):

If you still looking for such component you maybe should take a look at EasyQuery.NET:
http://devtools.korzh.com/query-builder-net-winforms/

Answer (score 3):

[Report Builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155933.aspx) is part of SQL Server Reporting Services, and it lets you do all of that and more. You can setup non-MSSQL data sources as well. We have non-developers use it all the time for creating reports with joins, grouping and so on with no SQL code.

The license is included in SQL Server Workgroup and above. I don't know if that's "free" enough for you.

Comment: Can this be deployed without installing the full SQL engine preferably as part of my own application?

Comment: It installs on top of IIS, and needs to be able to connect to a SQL Server to install its config DB. The IIS server can be on your app server.

Comment: Cool this may be an acceptable solution for one of my problems.  Thanks!  For the other situation I still need something really lightweight, that can be deployed as a DLL or a code library that I can just use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Aspose.Report AdHoc.WinForms](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/51/.net-components/aspose.report-for-.net/default.aspx) component (it is not free). It requires no SQL server running,  works fine with multiple tables and also have the ability to make automated table join.

Take a look at the component demo on Aspose site.

Comment: Looks like this product has now been discontinued by Aspose.

Comment: seems it is discontinued.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **CodeEngine.Framework** classes to select,insert,update,delete operations