# Is there an open source .Net SQL Editor component available?

Tags: .net, sql, components

I would like a text editor component that color codes SQL Statements like you would see in SQL Server Management Studio. I want to drop it on a form so I can write sql statements and send the queries to my database. It is not necessary to have intellisense but it would be a plus. Is there something like that out there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008154/net-query-builder-component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [someone asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087735/a-textbox-richtextbox-that-has-syntax-highlighting-c) and ended up being pointing to [ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/)

Comment: And it supports intellisense and code snippets too :)

Comment: That is for coding with, does not support SQL!

Answer (score 0):

Check this very nice editor: [SciTe](http://code.google.com/p/scite-ru/)

Answer (score 0):

The source to [Query Express](http://www.albahari.com/queryexpress.aspx) is available; I'm not sure how difficult it would be to integrate with your application.